# monaco-editor/react onClick event doesn't fire

Tags: reactjs, next.js, monaco-editor

I am using monaco-editor/react in my Next.js application, and everything works well.
I need to handle onClick event of the editor, but the event never fires.
here is my code:

```
import Editor from "@monaco-editor/react";
import { useRef, useState } from "react";

export default function MyEditor(){
    const editorRef = useRef(null);
    const [code,setCode]=useState("");

    function handleEditorDidMount(editor, monaco) {
        editorRef.current = editor;
    }

    function onChange(e) {
        setCode(e);
    }

    return(<Editor
            height="90vh"
            defaultLanguage="javascript"
            defaultValue="// some comment"
            value={code}
            onMount={handleEditorDidMount}
            onChange={onChange}
            onClick={() => {
              // this is never called
              alert("Clicked");
            }}
     />);
}
```

Comment: `onClick` s not supported in the props: https://github.com/react-monaco-editor/react-monaco-editor#properties

Answer (score 0):

`onClick` could be suppressed by the `Editor` package. In that case, maybe you can give this a shot.

```
  <div onClick={() => { alert('ddd' }}>
    <Editor ... />
  </div>
```

In theory this click can't be supressed.

Comment: thank you, I think I couldn't expose my problem.
I need event args passed by editor, indicating line number and column

Answer (score 0):

I am too stuck with this problem, so far I can console the click event and keypress. As there is no event for mouse click, I simply traced the click event and raise an alert, This way user can't open context menu.
Thank me later.

```
import Editor from "@monaco-editor/react";
import { useRef, useState } from "react";

export default function MyEditor(){
    const editorRef = useRef(null);
    const [code,setCode]=useState("");

    function handleEditorDidMount(editor, monaco) {
     editorRef.current = editor;
     editor.onKeyDown((event) => {
     console.log("event",event)
      const { keyCode, ctrlKey, metaKey } = event;
      if ((keyCode === 33 || keyCode === 52 || keyCode==93) && (metaKey || ctrlKey)){
        event.preventDefault();
        toast.show({
          status: "warning",
          title: "Don't copy paste your code.",
          placement: "top",
        });
      }
    });
    editor.onContextMenu((event)=>{
      console.log("event context",event)
    })
    
    editor.onMouseDown((event)=>{
      if(event?.event?.rightButton){
          alert("dont press right click")
          console.log("right click")
      }
    })
    }

    function onChange(e) {
        setCode(e);
    }

    return(<Editor
            height="90vh"
            defaultLanguage="javascript"
            defaultValue="// some comment"
            value={code}
            onMount={handleEditorDidMount}
            onChange={onChange}
            
     />);
}
```